# Play audio files from server Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, server

I created a sqlite database with table quote that have attribute id,text,audio.
My application listed all text quotes.Now I want to play audio of quotes listed.For the audios I put them in my server.Please I am asking for some ideas how to that.or tutorial.

Comment: You wants to convert text into audio?

Comment: I put a play button in list row that will play audio but don't have any idea how to call them from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get audio URL also with id, text and other info from server. Then use this code to play audio:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.
setDataSource(streamingURL);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thank you Ashiq it works :)

Comment: Where is my achievement then??? :p